# Terraform plugin development, where to specify version? best practices for go applications versioning?

Tags: terraform

We developed a couple of provider plugins for terraform, we did so without specifying version. Then for our own control we started to version using ldflags at build time:

```
go build -ldflags '-X \"main.VersionString=#{VERSION} (#{REVISION})\"' -o '#{WS}/#{PROJECT_NAME}' main.go"
```

and in the code:

```
package main

import(
  "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/plugin"
  ...
)

var VersionString = "unversioned"

func main(){
  if len(os.Args) == 2 && os.Args[1] == "--version" {
    fmt.Printf("Version %s\n", VersionString)
    os.Exit(0)
  }

  plugin.Serve(&plugin.ServeOpts{
    ProviderFunc: myprovider.Provider})
}
```

The problem is that terraform is unaware of the version, therefore we are not able to freeze version for our plugins.

What's the correct way to version custom plugins for terraform?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform plugins are not generally aware of their version number within the binary itself, but rather declare it as part of their filename.

For example, q provider plugin called "foo" might have a filename `terraform-provider-foo_v1.2.0` which then tells Terraform Core, when it finds that plugin, to treat it as version 1.2.0.